# Save optimizer state using Tensorflow Saved Format .pb

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have noticed that optimizer states are not saved for `.pb` saved models generated from the Tensorflow function `model.save(filepath)`.

When loading a given `.pb` model, its optimizer restarts from the beginning (the number of iterations is reset to zero).

One solution to solve this issue would be using the `.h5` format. I have saved a model with the function `model.save(filepath)`, where `filepath` is the path to a new h5 file and it seems that the optimizer state is well saved.

However, I am wondering if it is possible to save the optimizer state with the `.pb` format as I am planning to use Tensorflow Serving.

Here's my code :

I have a `callback.py` file containing a callback that is used to print the optimizer number of iterations :

```
class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
   def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
       print("Number of iterations : " , self.model.optimizer.iterations.numpy())
```

I saved a model (which is actually a folder containing the `.pb` model) with :

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(...)
model.add(...)
...

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3, batch_size=50, callbacks=[CustomCallback()])
model.save("saved_model", overwrite=True)
```

I tried to restart the training using :

```
model_loaded = keras.models.load_model('saved_model')
model_loaded.fit(x_train, y_train, initial_epoch=3, epochs=5, batch_size=50, callbacks=[CustomCallback()])
```

During training, I got :

```
Epoch 1/3
 9/10 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3259 Number of iterations :  10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 12ms/step - loss: 0.3249
Epoch 2/3
 9/10 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2987 Number of iterations :  20
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 0.2980
Epoch 3/3
 9/10 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2608 Number of iterations :  30
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 13ms/step - loss: 0.2586
```

After loading the saved model and retraining, I got :

```
Epoch 4/5
 9/10 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2166 Number of iterations :  10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 0.2148
Epoch 5/5
 6/10 [=================>............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.1861 Number of iterations :  20
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.1796
```

I am expecting the number of iterations for the 4th epoch to be 40.

Comment: To my understanding, model.save(checkpoint) should contain everything... Why it can miss your optimizer state :s? Do you have your code?

Comment: You can try to save by saver to maintain a good checkpoint
saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver()
saver.save(train_sess, "trainfolder/ckpt",global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

Comment: @dtlam26 I just uploaded my code.

Comment: saved_model and pb is considered as a static model which has been remove the optimizer from the training pipeline. Therefore, you can not load it and expect the optimizer to be kept. This is different than h5 file. When you load model from h5, there is a parameter "compile". If that is True, you load also your optimizer state, else no.

Comment: because of this incident, when you want to use the optimizer, I recommend you to save it as a checkpoint at first, then frozen graph or saved model can come along

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sounds like the best solution !

Comment: no problem. May be some one can come up with a better solution :))